# Mac OS X Server 10.6.7: Disable Apache?

Tags: osx-server, apache

I'm doing some Rails dev, and I'm trying to get [Pow](http://pow.cx) running. After making the appropriate symlink, if I try to go to `idealm_web.dev/` (`idealm_web` being the name of my Rails project), I get this:

[image: It's gorgeous, but useless right now.]

I was told that this was Apache. How do I disable this? I checked under System Preferences > Sharing, and there was no way to disable it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is OS X Server (i.e. the server product, not the regular desktop OS), turn off the web service in either Server Preferences or Server Admin.

Answer (score 4):

You could disable the launch daemon.

I'm not an expert with `launchctl` but the following command should work.

`sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist`

Comment: This worked for me and allowed MAMP to function properly on Mountain Lion. VPN however, ceased to work. It could be my fault, but just an October 2013 update on this for others.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off Web Sharing.  You might have to restart.  There are other ways of doing it also.  Keep searching.